# Origen de marrueco como cremallera

Tags: etimología, diferencias-regionales, chile, ropa

Aprendiendo un poco de 'chileno', pude darme cuenta que se usa el término *marrueco* como sinónimo de cremallera o bragueta ([Min. 3:03](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZqcbTXZ7r4) ), mas no le encuentro la relación. No se si haya alguien de Chile o si alguna otra persona sepa el porqué de la sinonimia entre estos términos.

Comment: Chile es un país que acostumbra, en la mayoría de los casos (incluyéndome), a torcer las acepciones de las palabras. No me extrañaría que la hayan adaptado así porque sí.

Comment: Mi respuesta no es documentada, sinó que la oí de una de mis abuelas, la materna creo... según ella los que introdujeron las "cremalleras" en Chile fueron unos inmigrantes marroquís, al igual que un pan que en Cataluña se llama yunget y que en Chile se conoce como marraqueta, pero esto es harina de otro costal...

Comment: @AndrésChandía tu teoria del origen de las marraquetas no parece ser siquiera tomada como posibilidad. Ver [aca](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marraqueta).

Comment: Bueno, en la Wikipedia todo son teorías, tampoco hay nada que sea concluyente, y aquí una foto del pan para que veas la similitud, lo había escrito mal, se llama (https://www.recordrentacar.com/blog/un-llonguet-por-favor-el-pan-mas-tipico-de-mallorca/) llonguet

Answer (score 3):

Esta obra postula que viene de [marroquí](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OU8MQOE#AXcsoLz) como sinónimo de [tafilete](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YwG5N7e), por el origen del material original de las portañuelas:

> **Marrueco**, m.
>
> *Portañuela, trampa ó trampilla:* «tira de tela con que se lapa la bragueta ó abertura que tienen los calzones y pantalones por delante».
>
> *Bragueta:* «abertura de los calzones ó pantalones por delante».
>
> — El nombre de **marrueco** que usamos nosotros en los dos significados anteriores, parece que se deriva del adj. *marrueco*, natural de Marruecos, y que es igual á *marroquí* ó *marroquín*, nombre que siempre hemos dado al *tafilete*. Probablemente la *portañuela* de los calzones y pantalones se haría antes de *tafilete*, y de ahí la confusión de estos nombres.
>
> - [*Diccionario de Chilenismos y de otras voces y locuciones viciosas*](https://archive.org/details/diccionariodechi03romuoft/page/444) (1901)

Answer (score 1):

**Origen de marrueco como cremallera**

---

**Marrueco**

*Bragueta «abertura de los calzones ó pantalones por delante»*.

---

Si bien hoy esta en desuso por "Morueco" (sim. marón), desde la antigüedad "**Marrueco**" fue voz muy utilizada para referirse a un carnero o macho ovino que utilizado especialmente en el ámbito rural para la reproducción de las ovejas. Aún durante el S. XVIII la voz "**Marrueco**" era de sobra conocida y utilizada como se ve en esta descripción de un texto de 1769.

---

[image]

---

Entre los consejos que se daban, se indicaba que cada Marrueco bastaba para cincuenta ovejas y podría ser utilizado entre tres y siete años, si bien en las tierras frías no iría más allá de un año. A partir del S. XIX se prefirió utilizar de nuevo la voz más tradicional, "morueco" (De marueco. Carnero padre o que ha servido para la propagación.) y que hoy en día aparece en la RAE.

---

**Marrueco en los Fueros**.

**Marueco o Marrueco** es la misma locución y es voz ya utilizada y constatada en antiguos documentos de la Edad Media, igualmente se han documentado otras variantes además de marrueco como morueco, marueco, morrueco, moruego, mureco, murueco...

Si bien la voz "Marueco o Marrueco" en la forma de "Morueco" ya se encuentra desde el año 1235 en el Fuero de Alcalá, no obstante, quise ampliar la búsqueda para ver cambios de grafía a lo largo del tiempo.

Así pues, en un recorrido por los distintos "Fueros", hallamos ambas grafías, "**Marueco y Marrueco**" en el "**Fuero General de Navarra**", surgido del "*Fuero Antiguo*" en el 1238 y al que se le fue añadiendo distintos capítulos a lo largo de los S. XIII y XIV. En el texto se puede comprobar que "Marueco o Marrueco" se refieren al mismo concepto.

Así en el en el Capitulo XIV [FGN, 5,7,14] podemos leer en romance;

> "Que calonia ha qui furtare o robare, o matare, o peyndrare barraco o
> **marueco**.
>
> "... Qui furtare el **marrueco** de las oveyllas, peyte la magadura
> como fuero es et un marrueco tant bueno como el suyo, et IX oveyllas
> preynados por calonia".

En estos textos se habla de las penas o multas para aquél que robe o mate al "marueco o marrueco" de las ovejas.

Por tanto, tenemos que **"Morueco, Marueco o Marrueco" es un carnero o macho ovino, utilizado o destinado para la reproducción de las ovejas**.

---

Los "marruecos" están en estado de engendrar corderos desde los 18 meses hasta los 7 u 8 años aproximadamente, pero es a los 3 cuando poseen más vigor. Así se habla de "cubrir el marrueco a la oveja" o echar el marrueco a las ovejas. Sin embargo, cuando los "marruecos" no tienen edad o las ovejas aún son demasiado jóvenes se utilizan distintos métodos para que éstas no queden embarazadas, ya sea poniéndole un delantal o mandil al macho o un parche a las más jóvenes.

Así pues, de esta antigua usanza de "**cubrir**" (*Estar [una cosa] delante o encima de otra, de manera que queda oculta o protegida*.) del léxico pastoril, procede la palabra "**Marrueco**", pues la costumbre existente entre los pastores y gente del campo era la de poner un trozo de tela, parche o badana (*piel curtida, suave y fina de carnero u oveja*) incluso alambre u otros materiales en torno al pene del "Marrueco", actualmente "morueco", para impedir que no cubriera o dejara embarazadas a las ovejas antes de los tres años.

Por extensión este parche de tela o piel tratada, que servía como "impedimento", tanto de modo de cierre como para cubrir y proteger a los pastores de otras inclemencias, se uso también para la elaboración de prendas, manteniendo la antigua costumbre de poner una "tela", "parche" o badana a modo de como se hacia con el "**marrueco**" para **tapar el pene** de éste e impedir que dejara embarazadas a las ovejas, de ahí el nombre, ya que **Marrueco**, según el diccionario de Chilenismos y de otras voces y locuciones viciosas
de Román, Manuel Antonio, (1901), hace referencia precisamente a la "**tira de tela con que se tapa** la bragueta o abertura que tienen los calzones y pantalones por delante", siendo en un principio aquella costumbre de poner una tira de tela al "marrueco", la que renombró al término.

[image]